# MongoDB UpdateOne Not Updating, Despite It Giving a Success Message

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So here is my database data;

```
"reviewers": [
            {
                "enrolledEventID": [],
                "enrolledId": [],
                "isOrganiser": false,
                "isAdmin": false,
                "forms": [],
                "userNotification": [],
                "isReviewer": true,
                "submissionsToReview": [],
                "_id": "5f926ea7c2cd694070f02c0a",
                "fullname": "Salman",
                "email": "salman1@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$NdRPKgYOvJt7.G1Ijh6Ii.sJnX2s4M48HyCdfmwU2OQ1JnFOD75LS",
                "__v": 0,
                "avatarImageSource": "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=Salman&size=64&rounded=true&background=random",
                "scores": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            {
                "enrolledEventID": [],
                "enrolledId": [],
                "isOrganiser": false,
                "isAdmin": false,
                "forms": [],
                "userNotification": [],
                "isReviewer": true,
                "submissionsToReview": [],
                "_id": "5f9655935c8ee155e86d723c",
                "fullname": "sadsad",
                "email": "sadsad@sadsad.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$T1yAtGrQy1UZnLoD3Bgm..yw9f2.pQqVsdlB7g5a9KK19TaEvwTNK",
                "__v": 0,
                "avatarImageSource": "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=sadsad&size=64&rounded=true&background=random",
                "scores": [
                    3,
                    2,
                    5
                ]
            },
            {
                "enrolledEventID": [],
                "enrolledId": [],
                "isOrganiser": false,
                "isAdmin": false,
                "forms": [],
                "userNotification": [],
                "isReviewer": true,
                "submissionsToReview": [
                    "5f7fe0fba09f2f30189d9b05"
                ],
                "_id": "5f99126693830c0c0ccc6db0",
                "fullname": "sad123",
                "email": "sad123@sad.com"
]
```

I want to update the scores inside reviewers and here is my code for that:

```
Enroll.updateOne(
  {
    _id: enrollID,
    "reviewers._id": userID,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "reviewers.$.scores": req.body.scores,
    },
  },
  (errUpdate, resultUpdate) => {
    if (errUpdate) {
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: errUpdate });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: resultUpdate });
    }
  }
);
```

It gives a success message, but the data isn't updated. I still go and check and the scores are as they were previously. Where am I making the mistake? Usually the Mongo errors give me a clue, but this time there are none.

Comment: Is `reviewers` a collection or a field in the `enroll` collection? If it is the latter, then your query is correct, make sure that the ids getting passed in the match clause are correct. `console.log` everything and make sure they have correct data types as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `req.body.scores` is an array of scores. If so, try this:

```
Enroll.updateOne(
  {
    _id: enrollID
  },
  {
    $set: {
      scores: req.body.scores,
    },
  },
  (errUpdate, resultUpdate) => {
    if (errUpdate) {
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: errUpdate });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: resultUpdate });
    }
  }
);
```